# Construct a Java PrivateKey object from an SSLeay formatted key

Tags: java, openssl, private-key

I am working on a Java (JSE 7) application that receives a private key in SSLeay format from an external server and needs to construct a java.security.PrivateKey-derived object. Since the key is received dynamically and the app is prohibited from using JNI, I'm not able to use openssl to convert the key.

Instead, I'm looking for a pure Java solution for converting from SSLeay to PKCS#8 or other format from which a PrivateKey can be constructed.

Googling shows a couple of third party libraries that handle SSLeay keys (eg, one from "Entrust") but am unfortunately constrained in this implementation to use no external libraries. Yes, I know. Not even Commons.

Does anybody know of any tools within the JSE 7 standard library that would help with this? I don't mind wading into writing the conversion myself, but have had a hard time locating a precise spec for SSLeay.

Thank you for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this answer is only useful if one is constrained, as I was, to avoid the use of any 3rd party libraries. If you're allowed to use BouncyCastle or other libraries, that's presumably a better way to go.

The key I was receiving was an RSA key in OpenSSL ("traditional SSLeay") DER format encoded to PEM. I was able to get a Java `java.security.PrivateKey` object in the following way:

1. Wrote a simplistic DER parser that only handles DER tag type 2 (integers). The parser had to handle reading the DER sequence tag (0x30) and fixed and variable length objects.
2. Used `String.replace` to get rid of the RSA key header and footer in the PEM string.
3. Used `DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary()` to get a byte array from the PEM string.
4. Used the DER parser to extract `BigInteger`s from the data: version, modulus, public exponent, private exponent, prime P, prime Q, prime exponent P, prime exponent Q, and CRT coefficient (in that order).
5. Created a `java.security.spec.RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec` object (`keySpec`) from those values.
6. `PrivateKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(keySpec);`

This worked for my purposes, but is an unfortunate reinvention of a couple of wheels.